# What is the unit SVG text coordinates?

Tags: svg, coordinates, coordinate-systems

H i all. Can someone explain me what is the unit of Svg text coordinates? And how we translate them to pixels? Thank U.

**Edit:**

Thanks to *Robert* to his answer; But I have a problem with using it. Here is my code:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"> 

<text x="23.5625" y="195.98749542236328" fill="red" style="font-size: 60px">Hi</text>

</svg>

<input style="position: absolute; left: 23.5625px; top: 195.987px">
```

Just make the page fullscreen, and try to zoom.

Comment: Searching "SVG units" yields many good explanations, including this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions

Answer (score 3):

Per [the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units) omitted units are the same as pixels.

> One px unit is defined to be equal to one user unit. Thus, a length of "5px" is the same as a length of "5".

Note that a viewBox applies a transform that makes the SVG responsive. If you want to match an absolutely positioned input then you don't want that. Also the baseline for text by default is the bottom of most letters, if we use hanging as the baseline instead then that will match the input.

I've also made the input opacity 0.5 so you can see the SVG is now underneath the input element.

```css
html, body, svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg> 

<text x="23.5625" y="195.98749542236328" fill="red" style="font-size: 20px;dominant-baseline: hanging;">Hi</text>

</svg>

<input style="position: absolute; left: 23.5625px; top: 195.987px;opacity: 0.5;">
```

Comment: Styling on SVG elements with `px` values will be translated into user units, but not the other way around. The amount of pixels something takes up on the screen is totally dependent on the size at which the SVG is displayed, among other things.

Comment: As I said that rather depends on whether you use a viewBox or not. If you don't then, unless you use transforms 1 user unit = 1px

Comment: I need viewBox to use. So what can I do?

Comment: put the html input element inside a foreignObject element inside your SVG

Comment: Love you! It helped me a lot :D